# should i use cross validation for getting my final model in caret?

Tags: caret

Hi I already use cv with grid search to find my best tune hyperparameter in caret. My question is, should I also use cv to get my final model, which I would use it to apply to the future data?
To put it another way, if I use cv with my best tuned parameter, the model I get is not trained on the entire dataset (as its 10 fold cv), so I should not use cv during the process, is that right?

Comment: Once you have tuned your hyperparameters using cross-validation on the training data, it is usual to estimate the actual parameters of your model using the whole training data - this second stage should not need cross-validation. You have not given the details of what you did with the `caret` package, but if you used `train()` then this may have already been done

Comment: That solves my doubt. Thanks! I think it's a general problem so did not provide any detail.

Comment: You can use cross-validation or bootstrapping on your "final" model in order to estimate the variance of its out-of-sample performance.

Comment: I have already done cv during the hyperparameter tuning step and can get the variance from that step by extracting all predictions corresponding to the test tune parameter. So I guess do it again is un-necessary?